# how to join lines in a diagram using tikz?

Tags: tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,positioning,shapes,arrows,decorations.markings,arrows.meta}

\tikzset{
      box/.style={draw,fill=white,rectangle,minimum size=2.5cm,align=center},
      diatostealth/.style={draw,{Diamond}-{Stealth}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[box](a){a}; 
\node[box, below left=1.5cm of a](b){b}; 
\node[box, below right=1.5cm of a](c){c}; 


% the arrows
\path[diatostealth] (a.south) -- (b.north){};
\path[diatostealth] (a.south) -- (c.north){};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: What I have]
    This is what I have currently.

[image: What I want]
This is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use intermediate coordinates. So the line on the left can be achieved by:

```
\path[diatostealth, thick] 
    (a.south) 
    -- ++(0,-0.5cm)
    -| (b.north)
    ;
```

means:

- start at `(a.south)`.
- the `++` means the coordinate which is `-0.5cm` below the last point,
- the `-|` means to draw a horizontal and then ventical line to the point `(b.north)`.

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,positioning,shapes,arrows,decorations.markings,arrows.meta}

\tikzset{
      box/.style={draw,fill=white,rectangle,minimum size=2.5cm,align=center},
      diatostealth/.style={draw,{Diamond}-{Stealth}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[box](a){a}; 
\node[box, below left=1.5cm of a](b){b}; 
\node[box, below right=1.5cm of a](c){c}; 


% the arrows
\path[diatostealth, thick] 
    (a.south) 
    -- ++(0,-0.5cm)
    -| (b.north)
    ;
\path[diatostealth, thick] 
    (a.south) 
    -- ++(0,-0.5cm)
    -| (c.north){};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

*If it looks like a tree, it should be a `forest`...*

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt,mult,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest,amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  my shadow/.style={drop shadow={shadow xshift=.25ex, shadow yshift=-.25ex}}
}

\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    draw,
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
    fill=white,
    my shadow,
    minimum width=20pt,
    text height=7.5pt,
    font=\sffamily,
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [-{Stealth[]}, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) node [inner sep=0pt, anchor=north, outer sep=0pt, scale=.5] {$\blacklozenge$} -- +(0,-5pt) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
  }
  [a
    [b]
    [c]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

[image: abc forest]

Comment: If it looks like a tree, it should be *in* a forest!

Comment: @HarishKumar Yes... ;) But ironically, it is exceedingly difficult to include two or more trees in a forest of this kind :(.